# do a "order by DESC or ASC" in a union with different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

Good day I need to sort by the `Fecha` column but when using `order by` I can not because the `select` in the `union` does not have the same columns. how could you sort by this field `Fecha`. Can you please help me solve this?
e.g. as below.

[image]

Below is the query i am using.

```
        SELECT 'PESO:','VOLUMEN:','NO. PIEZAS:','ETD:','ETA:'

        UNION ALL 


        SELECT
        (SELECT ISNULL(Valor,'') FROM MovCampoExtra WHERE Modulo = 'VTAS' AND ID = Venta.ID AND CampoExtra = 'CEDIS0103') AS pesoBruto,
        (SELECT ISNULL(Valor,'') FROM MovCampoExtra WHERE Modulo = 'VTAS' AND ID = Venta.ID AND CampoExtra = 'CEDIS0121') AS volumen,
        (SELECT ISNULL(Valor,'') FROM MovCampoExtra WHERE Modulo = 'VTAS' AND ID = Venta.ID AND CampoExtra = 'CEDIS0102') AS cantidadUnidades,
         (SELECT CEDIS0120 FROM VentaCampoExtra WHERE ID = Venta.ID) AS ETD,
            (SELECT CEDIS0123 FROM VentaCampoExtra WHERE ID = Venta.ID) AS ETA
            FROM Venta 
            --Venta AS v
        INNER JOIN Cte AS c ON c.Cliente = Venta.Cliente
            INNER JOIN Usuario us On us.Usuario = Venta.Usuario
        WHERE

            @Origen=Venta.TMLICentroCosto AND
            Venta.Mov IN ('Instruccion EXPO', 'Instruccion IMPO','Instruc. Nacional')
            AND Venta.Empresa IN ('TM')
            AND Venta.ID is NOT NULL 
            AND Venta.Estatus NOT IN ('Cancelado')


         UNION ALL 


        SELECT 'FECHA:','HORA:','ACTIVIDADES:',' ',' '

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT

            Fecha = ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, mb.Fecha, 103),''), -- AS Fecha,
            Hora = ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, mb.Fecha, 108),''), -- AS Hora,

            Comentarios = ISNULL(mb.Evento2,''),
            '',
            ''


            FROM Venta 
            --Venta AS v
        INNER JOIN Cte AS c ON c.Cliente = Venta.Cliente
            LEFT OUTER JOIN MovBitacora AS mb ON mb.ID = Venta.ID
            INNER JOIN Usuario us On us.Usuario = Venta.Usuario

        WHERE

            @Origen=Venta.TMLICentroCosto AND
            Venta.Mov IN ('Instruccion EXPO', 'Instruccion IMPO','Instruc. Nacional')
            AND Venta.Empresa IN ('TM')
            AND Venta.ID is NOT NULL 
            AND Venta.Estatus NOT IN ('Cancelado')
            ORDER BY Fecha ASC          

        RETURN
        END
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Your outer SELECT is simply UNIONing a row of non-aliased strings to another inner SELECT that's also UNIONing a row of non-aliased strings. You have no columns called "Fecha" in your SELECT. And why SELECT the rows for 'PESO:','VOLUMEN:','NO. PIEZAS:','ETD:','ETA:'? Did you want those to be column names instead of a row of strings?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so moaning out the way first, this is a horrible way to do things. You should not be returning header columns from the sql query, and hacking together two unrelated queries. This should be two queries called by the application layer, which should also be handling the headers.

But if you have to do it this way for some arcane reason, you could add a "sorting" column to each query

```
Header 1 sortval = A
Peso query sortval = B + Peso
Header 2 sortval = C
Fecha query sortval = D + Fecha (in YYYYMMDD format)
```

Then add a big select round the whole thing to select the columns (which you will need to add aliases for in the first header select) and order by the sortval.